# I have a data buffer containing hex string values and I want to segregate them into different structures in C

Tags: c

```c
uint8_t data_buff[] = {0x53, 0x49, 0x5A, 0x45, 0x20, 0x37, 0x36, 0x2E, 0x32,
    0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x35, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x38, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D,
    0x0D, 0x0A, 0x42, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x45, 0x20, 0x33, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D,
    0x2C, 0x20, 0x30, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x44, 0x49, 0x52, 0x45,
    0x43, 0x54, 0x49, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x20, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x52,
    0x45, 0x46, 0x45, 0x52, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x43, 0x45, 0x20, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x30,
    0x0D, 0x0A, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x46, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54, 0x20, 0x30, 0x20, 0x6D,
    0x6D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54, 0x20, 0x50, 0x45, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x20,
    0x4F, 0x46, 0x46, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54, 0x20, 0x43, 0x55, 0x54,
    0x54, 0x45, 0x52, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x46, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54,
    0x20, 0x50, 0x41, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x41, 0x4C, 0x5F, 0x43, 0x55, 0x54,
    0x54, 0x45, 0x52, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x46, 0x0D, 0x0A};

// above string values converted
//   SIZE 76.2 mm, 50.8 mm..BLINE 3 mm, 0 mm..DIRECTION 0,0..REFERENCE 0,0.
//   .OFFSET 0 mm..SET PEEL OFF..SET CUTTER OFF..SET PARTIAL_CUTTER OFF
```

I want to segregate the data into different arrays, one containing the letters and the other containing its corresponding numeric values.

I have made the following command but am unable to put a carriage return after every word in caps. Also, I am unable to figure out how to extract their corresponding numeric values and save them in reference to the work for e.g. `SIZE` and it has two numeric values which should pointed by it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  uint8_t m = 0, j = 0, k = 0, i = 0, temp_buff[150] = {0}, command_buff[150] =
      {0};
  uint8_t data_buffer[] = {0x53, 0x49, 0x5A, 0x45, 0x20, 0x37, 0x36, 0x2E, 0x32,
      0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x35, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x38, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D,
      0x0D, 0x0A, 0x42, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x45, 0x20, 0x33, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D,
      0x2C, 0x20, 0x30, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x44, 0x49, 0x52, 0x45,
      0x43, 0x54, 0x49, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x20, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x52,
      0x45, 0x46, 0x45, 0x52, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x4};
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data_buffer); i++) /*FOR LOOP EXECUTES TILL END OF BUFFER*/
  {
    if ((data_buffer[i] == (0x20))
        || ((data_buffer[i] > (0x40) && (data_buffer[i] < (0x5B)))))
        /*When hex value 0x20(space) is present in temp_buff*/
        {
      command_buff[k] = data_buffer[i];
      printf("\n %x:%c", command_buff[k], command_buff[k]);
    }
  }
  getchar();
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do. It will be easier to achieve by studying your code with consistent indentation.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. I guess the goal is to parse the given string, but you very badly defined how it should be parsed. Why do you want to put cariage return after words ? You want insert a cariage return to output, or in the buffer ? There are MANY solutions to isolate things, but the first thing you need is syntactic rules. The given string have some rules (carriage returns, commas) but also include irregularity such as unit "mm".

Comment: those are not string values.

Comment: Any reason you don't convert this to a null-terminated string so you can use the string functions like `strtok()`?

Comment: It is extremely unclear how you want to store the information - for example you say arrays but how do you know how big to make them or how many you need?  If you need help parsing the data look at this: https://onlinegdb.com/_I6yBVmw1

Comment: The parsing is easy, but if you have some idea of what kind of structures you want to use to store the data edit the question so we can help more.